Здравствуйте! Прошу помочь со школьным проектом. Мне задали сделать телеграмм бота
Проблема в том, что сообщение с инлайн клавиатурой есть, но нажатия никак не считываются. Я нажимаю на кнопку, она секунд 15 горит и все. Никаких нужных сообщений, да и вообще никаких сообщений после нажатия нет. Помогите пожалуйста исправить. Заранее спасибо!
import asyncio
import logging
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, types
from aiogram.types import InlineKeyboardMarkup, InlineKeyboardButton


API_TOKEN = 'Мой токен'
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
bot = Bot(token=API_TOKEN)
dp = Dispatcher(bot)


inline_kb_list = InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width = 1)
inline_kb_list.add(
    InlineKeyboardButton(text="Классическая русская литература", callback_data='Классическая русская'),
    InlineKeyboardButton(text="Классическая зарубежная литература", callback_data='Классическая зарубежная'),
    InlineKeyboardButton(text="Современная литература", callback_data='Современная'),
    InlineKeyboardButton(text="Фантастика и фэнтези", callback_data='Фантастика и фэнтези'),
    InlineKeyboardButton(text="Подростковая литература", callback_data='Подростковая')
)



@dp.message_handler(commands=["start"])
async def answer(message: types.Message):
    await message.answer('Выбери жанр литературы, который хочешь почитать!', reply_markup=inline_kb_list)

@dp.callback_query_handler()
async def callback_query_keyboard(callback_query: types.CallbackQuery):
    await call.answer()
    if callback_query.data == "Классическая русская":
        await bot.send_message(chat_id = callback_query.from_user.id, text = "Классическая русская")
    elif callback_query.data == "Классическая зарубежная":
        await bot.send_message(chat_id = callback_query.from_user.id, text = "Классическая зарубежная")
    elif callback_query.data == "Современная":
        await bot.send_message(chat_id = callback_query.from_user.id, text = "Современная")
    elif callback_query.data == "Фантастика и фэнтези":
        await bot.send_message(chat_id = callback_query.from_user.id, text = "Фантастика и фэнтези")
    else:
        await bot.send_message(chat_id = callback_query.from_user.id, text = "Подростковая")



Janry = {'Классическая русская литература': ["Н. М. Карамзин: *Наталья, боярская дочь*", "Н. В. Гоголь: *Ревизор*", "Н. В. Гоголь: *Шинель*", "А. С. Пушкин: *Капитанская дочка*", "М. Ю. Лермонтов: *Мцыри*", "И. С. Тургенев: *Ася*", "А. П. Чехов: *Человек в футляре*", "А. П. Чехов: *Крыжовник*", "А. П. Чехов: *О любви*", "М. Горький: *Челкаш*", "М. Горький: *Как поймали Семагу*", "А. П. Платонов: *Возвращение*", "А. Т. Твардовский: *Василий Теркин*"],
              'Классическая зарубежная литература':["У. Шекспир: *Ромео и Джульетта*", "Мольер: *Мещанин во дворянстве*", "В. Скотт: *Айвенго*"],
              'Современная литература': ["Ю. Яковлева: *Ленинградские сказки*", "Г. Шмидт: *Битвы по средам*", "Р. Стед: *Шпион и лжец*", "Ш. Дрейпер: *Привет, давай поговорим*", "Р. Дж. Паласио: *Чудо*", "С. Таунсенд: *Тайный дневник Адриана Моула*", "Д. Доцук: *Голос*", "Т. Штрассер: *Волна*", "Д. Бойн: *Мальчик в полосатой пижаме*", "М. Зусак: *Воровка книг*"],
              'Фантастика и фэнтези': ["В. П. Крапивин: *Голубятня на желтой поляне*", "В. П. Крапивин: *В глубине Великого Кристалла*", "В. П. Крапивин: *Самолет по имени Сережка*", "В. П. Крапивин: *Лето кончится не скоро*", "Л. Лоури: *Дающий*", "Э. Мандел: *Станция Одиннадцать*", "Дж. Р. Р. Толкин: *Властелин Колец*"],
              'Подростковая литература': []}

dlitelnost = {'Короткие произведения' : ["Н. В. Гоголь: *Шинель*", "А. П. Чехов: *Человек в футляре*", "А. П. Чехов: *Крыжовник*", "А. П. Чехов: *О любви*", "М. М. Зощенко: *История болезни*", "М. М. Зощенко: *Аристократка*", "М. М. Зощенко: *Диктофон*", "Ю. Яковлева: *Ленинградские сказки*", "Р. Стед: *Шпион и лжец*", "Ш. Дрейпер: *Привет, давай поговорим*", "Д. Доцук: *Голос*", "Д. Бойн: *Мальчик в полосатой пижаме*"],
              'Средние произведения' : ["Н. М. Карамзин: *Наталья, боярская дочь*", "М. Ю. Лермонтов: *Мцыри*", "И. С. Тургенев: *Ася*", "А. С. Пушкин: *Капитанская дочка*", "Н. В. Гоголь: *Ревизор*", "М. Горький: *Челкаш*", "Г. Шмидт: *Битвы по средам*", "Р. Дж. Паласио: *Чудо*", "С. Таунсенд: *Тайный дневник Адриана Моула*", "Т. Штрассер: *Волна*", "В. П. Крапивин: *Голубятня на желтой поляне*", "В. П. Крапивин: *В глубине Великого Кристалла*", "В. П. Крапивин: *Самолет по имени Сережка*", "В. П. Крапивин: *Лето кончится не скоро*", "Л. Лоури: *Дающий*", "Дж. Грин: *Виноваты звезды*"],
              'Длинные произведения' : ["А. П. Платонов: *Возвращение*", "А. Т. Твардовский: *Василий Теркин*", "У. Шекспир: *Ромео и Джульетта*", "В. Скотт: *Айвенго*", "Э. Мандел: *Станция Одиннадцать*", "Дж. Р. Р. Толкин: *Властелин Колец*"],
    }

Slozhnost = {'Легкие' : ["М. М. Зощенко: *История болезни*", "М. М. Зощенко: *Аристократка*", "М. М. Зощенко: *Диктофон*", "Ю. Яковлева: *Ленинградские сказки*", "Р. Стед: *Шпион и лжец*", "Ш. Дрейпер: *Привет, давай поговорим*", "Д. Доцук: *Голос*", "Д. Бойн: *Мальчик в полосатой пижаме*", "В. П. Крапивин: *Голубятня на желтой поляне*", "В. П. Крапивин: *В глубине Великого Кристалла*", "В. П. Крапивин: *Самолет по имени Сережка*", "В. П. Крапивин: *Лето кончится не скоро*", "Л. Лоури: *Дающий*", "Дж. Грин: *Виноваты звезды*"],
             'Средние' : ["Н. В. Гоголь: *Ревизор*", "Н. В. Гоголь: *Шинель*", "А. С. Пушкин: *Капитанская дочка*", "А. П. Чехов: *Человек в футляре*", "А. П. Чехов: *Крыжовник*", "А. П. Чехов: *О любви*", "Г. Шмидт: *Битвы по средам*", "Р. Дж. Паласио: *Чудо*", "С. Таунсенд: *Тайный дневник Адриана Моула*",  "Т. Штрассер: *Волна*", "Дж. Р. Р. Толкин: *Властелин Колец*"],
             'Сложные' : ["Н. М. Карамзин: *Наталья, боярская дочь*", "М. Ю. Лермонтов: *Мцыри*", "И. С. Тургенев: *Ася*", "А. П. Платонов: *Возвращение*", "А. Т. Твардовский: *Василий Теркин*", "У. Шекспир: *Ромео и Джульетта*", "В. Скотт: *Айвенго*", "М. Горький: *Челкаш*", "Э. Мандел: *Станция Одиннадцать*"]
    }




async def main():
    await dp.start_polling(bot)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())

Весь код я копировал со всяких видео на ютубе и сайтов в интернете.

Ух ты, в школах боты для Телеграм задают писать? Наверное, я что-то проспал в школьной программе.

await call.answer() - а откуда взялась переменная call? По идее ваш код должен был выдать ошибку, проверьте консоль там, где вы бота запускали. Вы невнимательно скопировали код. Во-первых этот кусок кода тут вообще не нужен, вы же ничего дополнительно не спрашиваете в этом месте у пользователя, во-вторых у вас такой переменной call нет в сигнатуре функции, да вообще нигде нет.
